# JTable Empty cell validation for the filled rows

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am doing a project in java swing in which I have to use a JTable. 
By default jtable can validate the inputs (float,int) by turning into red when wrong input is given.
But I want to validate the empty cell left in the table at the time of save button click.

Here is my code:

```
public boolean validCheck() {

    if (jTable.getCellEditor() != null) {
        jTable.getCellEditor().stopCellEditing();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < jTable3.getRowCount(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < jTable3.getColumnCount(); j++) {
             String val = jTable3.getValueAt(row, col).toString();

             if (val.trim().length() == 0) {
                return false;(joptionpane.showmessagedialog(null,"field empty");)
             }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

This code is checking all the rows in the table and displaying the field empty message. I need to check only filled rows(rows which have data) not all the rows in the jtable.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your logic to first look if a row had data at all.  Then (and only then), take a second pass to validate that all columns in that row are filled.

Comment: can you give me a hint on getting the rows which only have data.

Comment: i am not getting the idea to get the rows only with data can somebody help me out with this...?

Comment: You already have this line of code "if (val.trim().length() == 0 )".  Make a pass across the entire row and if everything is empty there no data in that row.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply...."Make a pass across entire row".i didn't get that..could you please explain it more..

Comment: You already have the code.  You are doing it now, you would just need to small amount of logic to exclude empty rows.

Comment: I am a newbie in java and i could not implement the logic for this problem .Help me with some code..how should i exclude empty rows.

Comment: Then it sounds like the answer is you need a tutor.  Don't mean to sound rough.